# Frequent change of ssl certificate impedes java-https programmatic connectivity.What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool, apache-httpcomponents

I'm not familiar with the certificate stuff.I followed various resources in here about importing certificate into my store using keytool etc.

I'm able to connect via Http Components library with all this done.What I do notice is everyday or in a few days time the certificate stuff keeps changing i.e 
this content retrieved from OpenSSL using

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect amazon:443 >public.crt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE/zCCA+egAwIBAgIIGtXQnQA.........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and when this happens it fails with the PKIX error.I then have to redo all this stuff i.e delete the existing alias from my keystore and then reimport the certificate.Only then my program runs.

Am I doing something wrong here?Right now it is just some testing that I'm doing but I can't see progressing down this line if I have to use this approach in production.

Please help.

Comment: What certificates are changing? The whole chain or just the server certificate? Ideally in the real world, it wouldn't happen so frequently as you are seeing now.

Answer (score 0):

Except for a server within your own organization or a closely allied one using a selfsigned cert, you should never need to manually trust (import to truststore) a leaf cert; only in rare cases should you import an additional CA (root) cert and when you do those should almost never change.

'amazon' doesn't really identify a server. If you mean the worldwide company [www.]amazon.com they don't have just one server but hundreds or thousands, which might or might not be using the same cert at the same time or different times. OT1H https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.amazon.com currently sees them at 52.84.239.51 while in a different part of the US I see a different address, but both are (currently) using the cert with SHA256 fingerprint  6aa0ab97d0f9f1505896313be2372dc394bd427757f6bdb62dde80ed54d4190d . OTOH the transparency log at https://crt.sh/?q=amazon.com shows 12 currently valid certs for different subsets of (the domainnames of) various Amazon sites; Mexico and Brazil in particular have their own certs for some reason. All are from Symantec and thus presumably chain to VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 and therefore should verify with the builtin cacerts in any Sun/Oracle Java release since 6u24 in 2011 per my records; for IBM I don't know and for OpenJDK it may depend on your packager/builder but any reasonably up-to-date system should have VerisignC3G5, and if not that's a problem you can specifically fix.

OT3H it's possible that someone has been poisoning or spoofing your DNS and you've actually been importing the certificate from, and connecting to, criminals who have stolen and/or changed your data. That's the disadvantage of 'fixing' security problems by ignoring them.

If you want to try to figure out what's going on try actually looking at the certs you are getting instead of blindly trusting them, and in particular check if they do or do not match the ones in the transparency log(s). It is possible Amazon have additional cert(s) (from someone other than Symantec) that aren't logged, for such a prominent and important company I'd doubt it.